# Brownian motion integrated with repect to time

Tags: stochastic-processes, expected-value, stochastic-analysis

Consider $X_t= \int_0^t W_s ds $ where $W$ denotes a Brownian motion.

I want to compute: $E[X_t]$. Using $E[W_t]=0$ yields  $E[X_t]=0$

This relies on interchanging the order of integration. Why can I do that in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\int_{\Omega} \int_0^{t} |W_s| dsdP=\int_0^{t}\int_{\Omega} |W_s|dP ds=\int_0^{t} \sqrt s cds<\infty$ where $c=E|X|$ when $X \sim N(0,1)$. Hence Fubini/Tonelli theorem can be used to justify interchange of integral and expectation.

Comment: How do you compute $E[|W_s|]=\sqrt{s} c$?

Comment: @Sarah $W_s$ has normal distribution with mean $0$ and variance $s$. If we define $X$ as $\frac 1 {\sqrt s} W_s$ then $X$ is normal with mean $0$ and variance $\frac  1 s var(W_s)=1$. Hence we have $X \sim N(0,1)$ and $W_s-=\sqrt s X$.

Comment: Thank you, but we consider in this case the modulus of $W_s$. Why does this make no difference?

Comment: @Sarah Since $W_s=\sqrt s X$ we have $E|W_s|=E\sqrt s |X|=\sqrt s  c$.

Comment: Sorry you defined $c$ as the modulus of the expected value of $X$. We have to know that is expected value is finite. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Sarah $E|X|\leq \sqrt {EX^{2}} =1$.

Comment: Thank you very much.